# CSS not found Dyson Module node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules

I am using the Dyson module on Node js but my app doesn't find the css folder. 
I have this:

```
 /demoDyson
    dyson-demo.js
    /node_modules
    /public
        /css
          style.css
    /services
      /GET
         _index.js
         test.js
```

**dyson-demo.js** :

```
var express = require('express'),
    dyson = require('dyson'),
    path = require('path');

dyson.bootstrap({
    configDir: __dirname + '/services',
    port: 8765
});

var myApp = express();
myApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**_index.js** :

```
module.exports = {
 path: '/',
 render: function(req, res) {

    var html = '<h1>dyson</h1><p>Example endpoints:</p>';

    var examples = [
        '/test'
    ];

    html += '<ul>' + examples.map(function(example) {
        return '<li><a href="' + example + '">' + example + '</a></li>';
    }).join('') + '</ul>';

    res.send(200, html);
 }
};
```

**test.js** :

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   path: '/test',
   render: function (req, res) {    
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../../public/index.html'));
 }
};
```

Now, to load the index.html file in public folder, the browser console says that the css not found.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you run dyson API, it doesn't get combined with express middleware. What I would suggest you to do is, just use `'./' + pathToTheFile` or you can upload your css files online with `.css` extension and then link it to your html.

Comment: I have already tried this solution but the console show me the same error :(

Comment: since it's a server already, i suggest you to create new links with an extension of **`.css`** in your website, put the css code in there, and link it to your html like that @rubotero